# Laço de repetição json php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Recebo um json via post php, e quero inserir as informações em uma tabela no banco mysql..

```
json{  { "todos": [{ "nome0": "andre", "cor0": "preta" }, { "nome1": "felipe", "cor1": "azul" }, { "nome2": "laura", "cor2": "rosa" } ] }
```

Codigo php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    require_once("dbConnect.php");

    // Definir UTF8

    mysql_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

    $tamanho = $_POST['tamanhoArray'];
    $tamArray = (int)$tamanho;
    $jsonALL = $_POST['todos'];
    $jsonParse = json_decode($jsonALL, true);

    for($i = 0;$i<$tamArray;$i++)
    {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO PEDIDOS (nomeUsuario, corUsuario) VALUES ('$jsonParse->nome.$i','$jsonParse->cor.$i')";

        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

            echo "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso";

        }else{

            echo "Erro ao adicionar usuário";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);


}else{

  echo "Requisição inválida   ";

}
```

Comment: Use o `foreach` com o `$jsonParse`, acredito que irá facilitar. Também, pode criar um método separado de inserção, assim melhor organiza seu código. Ex. `insereRegistro($nome, $cor)`. E outra coisa, seu JSON não é válido.

Comment: Qual o problema que está tendo?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo concatenar a variavel $i com a $jsonParse.

Comment: @Petruceli.L, seu JSON está decodificando ? Porque do jeito que passou, está errado. O correto seria: `{
 "todos": [{
   "nome1": "andre",
   "cor1": "preta"
  },
  {
   "nome2": "felipe",
   "cor2": "azul"
  },
  {
   "nome3": "laura",
   "cor3": "rosa"
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: se eu colocar jsonParse->nome1 da certo , mas se coloca jsonParse->nome.$i nao da certo, registra apenas os valores de $i no banco

Comment: RBZ desculpe a forma que escrevi, mas o json esta funcionando perfeitamente. é realmente da forma que vc escreveu. obrigado

Comment: @Petruceli.L o seu json continua errado. Use um validador para conferir. Ex.: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evite usar `"nome0", "nome1", "nome2",...`, se não você terá infinitas propriedades, e teria que fazer uma "gambiarra" para ficar tratando sua `string`.

O `"nome"` já seria uma propriedade, então não tem porque colocar `0,1,2,3...`, pois isso só dará mais trabalho para gerar o seu `json` para envio, e novamente para o `php` receber e tratar como `array`.

Basicamente assim:

```
<?php

// Seu json
$json = '{
    "todos": [{
        "nome": "andre",
        "cor": "preta"
    }, {
        "nome": "felipe",
        "cor": "azul"
    }, {
        "nome": "laura",
        "cor": "rosa"
    }]
}';

// "Transformando" o json em array
$array = json_decode($json, true);

//echo '<pre>'; // Exibir com pré formatação
//print_r($array);

// Loop no índice "todos"
foreach($array['todos'] as $v){

    // Função para inserir
    insereRegistro($v['nome'],$v['cor'])
}

// Função que recebe as variáveis e insere o registro
private function insereResgistro($nome, $cor) {

    //Seu método para inserir no banco
    $sql = "INSERT INTO PEDIDOS (nomeUsuario, corUsuario) VALUES ('{$nome}','{$cor}')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        echo "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso";
    else
        echo "Erro ao adicionar usuário";

    mysqli_close($con);
}    

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Criando Json
$myArray[] = array("nome"=>"elder", "sobrenome"=>"barbosa", "idade"=>34);
$myArray[] = array("nome"=>"Luanna", "sobrenome"=>"Paz", "idade"=>31);
$myJSON = json_encode(array("usuario"=>$myArray), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

echo "MyJson print => ". $myJSON."<br>";// Imprimindo json

// Decodificando o json
$retorno = json_decode($myJSON);
foreach($retorno->usuario as $usuario){
    echo "Nome: ". $usuario->nome."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente desta maneira.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    require_once("dbConnect.php");

    // Definir UTF8

    mysql_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

    $tamanho = $_POST['tamanhoArray'];
    $tamArray = (int)$tamanho;
    $jsonALL = $_POST['todos'];
    $jsonParse = json_decode($jsonALL, true);

    for($i = 0;$i<$tamArray;$i++)
    {

        $nome = "nome".$i;
        $cor = "cor".$i;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO PEDIDOS (nomeUsuario, corUsuario) VALUES ('$jsonParse->$nome','$jsonParse->$cor')";

        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

            echo "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso";

        }else{

            echo "Erro ao adicionar usuário";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);


}else{

  echo "Requisição inválida   ";

}
```